# How do I stop eclipse from auto creating filters for android logcat?

Tags: android, eclipse, filter, adt, logcat

After an update my eclipse started to create filters automatically for LogCat.

I don't really mind if it creats those useless filters, but it always auto-select the one I least want to look at.

Is there a way to disable this auto-filter feature?

Answer (score 10):

Try disabling: Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Logcat -> Display logcat view when there are messages from an app in workspace (as it was described in this issue in Android bug tracker: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20965)

Comment: The link you've pointed to does not address the OP's issue - it talks about stealing focus from other windows.