# Prevent LogCat Session Filter from stealing focus

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I've setup a series of Filters for logcat and would like to keep focus on a specific filter, however whenever the Session Filter receives a message it steals focus from my desired filter.

I've been unable to find any reference on the net, nor any settings in eclipse. Can I prevent the Session Filter from stealing focus?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just to update because it's changed a little bit since this post.

For me, a box labeled: `Monitor logcat for messages from applications in workspace` needs to be unticked in your eclipse > window > preferences -> Android -> LogCat, shown here:

[image: disable automatic eclipse focus when debugging app]

---

Found the answer here: [How do I stop eclipse from auto creating filters for android logcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042145/how-do-i-stop-eclipse-from-auto-creating-filters-for-android-logcat)

This can be accomplished by disabling **Display logcat view when there are messages from an app in workspace.** Here's what that looks like in eclipse:

[image]